# _BROWSER_ has prevented an outdated plugin "Adobe Flash" from running on this site

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, flash, fancybox

*Update 23/8/17: Link added.*

I'm facing the following issue on our [webshop](http://www.trinit.hu):

After updating to **WINDOWS 10 1703** our website is loading as usual but after a few sec the following popup message comes up:
'BROWSER' has prevented an outdated plugin "Adobe Flash" from running on this site. It occurs in IE and Chrome as well, although it doesn't have this issue on older versions of Windows or the latest MAC OS, or on mobile browsers.

There were already a couple of things I tried:

1. Reinstalling flash
2. Enabling and disabling the preference of HTML over flash and even tried with the local group policies in windows, but the issue still appears.

The 'funniest' part is that I'm not aware of the situation that we have any flash object on the site. When I was scrolling the source code there where just a few instances where I found something related to flash:

1. a flash player version checker - javascript (inside the client.js on the site)
2. in the fancybox jquery

Can these trigger this behavior?

Is there anybody who has experienced something similar lately? Is there a workaround to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I can't see how the Javascript flash version checker would work without creating an instance of a flash player object and querying it.  That would require the flash plugin to be installed and allowed.  Regardless, if you don't use flash then get rid of that anyway.

Comment: Thanks, will try it and hope this solves this issue.

Comment: _"...the following issue on our webshop"_ where's the link to check this issue?

Comment: Hi, I have added the link to the main description.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that fancyBox is not related to this, unless it is used to display some flash content, but then it would be quite noticeable :)

Quite possible that "flash player version checker" creates some flash object to check for supported version. Try to disable it.